# adding hibernate option in power menu on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, hibernate

I recently updated to Ubuntu 18.04 (indeed re-installed due to a failed update).

`sudo systemctl hibernate` worked [after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067410/ubuntu-18-04-update-hibernate-hangs) adding the swap partition UUID into grub. 
Then, I modified the content of `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla` `[Disable hibernate by default in upower]` and `[Disable hibernate by default in logind]` sections 
as below:

```
ResultActive=yes
```

and created `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla` with the following content:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

according to [this](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2017/05/03/re-enable-hibernate-ubuntu-17-04/) guide.

Nevertheless, my power menu still does not contain the Hibernate option. What have I to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called **[Hibernate Status Button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/755/hibernate-status-button/)** to get a hibernate button. This extension

> Adds a Hibernate button in Status menu. Using Alt modifier, you can also select Hybrid Sleep instead.

[image]

Also check the extension's [GitHub page](https://github.com/arelange/gnome-shell-extension-hibernate-status).